# A Euclidean valuation on a Euclidean domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Here is the full information needed to start this problem:

Prove or disprove the following statement:

> If $v$ is a Euclidean valuation on a Euclidean domain $D$, then $\{a\in D: v(a)>v(1)\}\cup\{0\}$ is an ideal of $D$.

Here are some of my thoughts about this problem that are giving me trouble starting.

We know that a Euclidean domain is defined by $D$ and the valuation is denoted by v respectively. There are two conditions that we might have to concern ourselves with regarding if for some $a,b$ nonzero elements in $D$ then $v(a)$ is less than or equal to $v(ab)$. Also, if $a,b$ are in $D$ and $b$ is not $0$ then there must be some $q,r$ in $D$ that satisfy the Euclidean algorithm $a=bq+r$ and where $r=0$ or $v(r)<v(b)$.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: For future reference: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/155/22428

Comment: @user I had always thought that this would fall into valuation theory, but yeah as I read about it is probably not the case. Swapped the tag for ring-theory because I couldn't think of anything better.

Comment: Thank you for the lesson in proper English @rschwieb, so silly of me to ask a question about Math and get back a lesson in English in a mathematics forum. Though I do appreciate your wit.

Comment: Dear @user110655 : Sorry, I did not mean any offense. I was just trying to help discreetly. If I can remember your randomly generated user number, I will leave whatever awkward grammar I find in your posts alone.  Regards

Comment: @rschwieb I apologize for taking offense and should have considered your remarks with higher regard. I appreciate your input

Answer (score 2):

It is not an ideal in general. The problem is that it does not neeed to be closed under addition.

More specifically, assume that $D$ is a Euclidean domain which is not a field and which is not local, i.e. there exist at least two (non-associated) prime elements $p_1, p_2 \in D$, together  with a Euclidean valuation $v$. Then, since $p_1, p_2$ are non-invertible, it is easy to see that $v(p_i)>1, \; i=1,2$. Since $p_1, p_2$ are non-associated primes, they are coprime and, since $D$ is a PID, there exist elements $\alpha, \beta \in D$ such that $\alpha p_1+\beta p_2=1$. But then the set $M:=\{a \in D \;|\; v(a)>1\}$ is not closed under addition, since $\alpha p_1, \beta p_2 \in M$ and $1 \notin M$.